# Browser JSON Plugins

Tags: json, browser, safari, plugins

Im looking for a Safari/Webkit plugin similar to Firefox's JSONView, or the Pretty JSON Chrome extension. Anyone know of anything like this?

- JSONView - http://benhollis.net/blog/2009/02/24/jsonview-view-json-documents-in-firefox/
- Pretty JSON - https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ddngkjbldiejbheifcmnfmmfiniimbbg

Comment: I came across this question whilst looking for a JSON visualization plugin... Pretty JSON didn't work for me on Chrome (and I didn't like the fact that you needed to add a .json extension), so instead I used JSON formatter here https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa

Answer (score 42, accepted):

And even easier, with Safari 5: https://github.com/rfletcher/safari-json-formatter

Comment: This plugin might not work with Safari 6 https://github.com/rfletcher/safari-json-formatter/issues/25

Comment: Seems to be working quite well on my Safari 6 here.

Comment: Worked for me with Safari 6.1.1. Great tool!

Comment: Seems to work great on Safari 7.0.5!

Comment: Just for the update, seems to be working on 8.0 in OS X 10.10 as well.

Comment: Still working with 8.0.2.

Comment: No longer works for Version 6.2.6 (8537.85.15.3)

Comment: Ouch. Not working in Safari 8.0.6.

Answer (score 4):

I recently made a JSON viewer for safari called JSONAce, you can download it here:
https://github.com/acrogenesis/JSONAce

[Apple Extensions link](https://extensions.apple.com/details/?id=com.acrogenesis.jsonace-56Q494QF3L)

Comment: I downloaded the extension for Safari 8.0.2 and it doesn't seem to work

Comment: works ok on my mac @htafoya

Comment: It works on my Mac too! Safari 8.0.2

Comment: How to install this? Please add the link directly to the extension. Pardon , new to safari extensions.

Comment: @pal4life here's the direct link on apple's safari extension gallery https://extensions.apple.com/details/?id=com.acrogenesis.jsonace-56Q494QF3L

Comment: @acrogenesis FYI The extensions links are broken. I couldn't find when searching the gallery either.

Comment: @wst Install it via github https://github.com/acrogenesis/JSONAce apple changed its policies and because I don't have a developer account I can't publish to the gallery.

Comment: @acrogenesis JSONAce has a major bug. If you visit a url that displays JSON. Then change the url to another JSON page it locks up Safari and your computer with 100% CPU usage.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [xmlview](http://www.entropy.ch/software/MacOSX/xmlviewplugin/) plugin

New link seems to be https://github.com/sergeche/xmlview

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. I was fooled by a moment by the name of the extension but it also allows for JSON. Thanks!

Comment: From my experience it doesn't work for Safari 6 anymore.

Comment: nothing works with safari 6 anymore!

Comment: Link does not work anymore

Answer (score 1):

This the best and easiest plugin to install:

Named: [JSON Formatter](http://safariextendr.com/extension/json-formatter#.U3sEp_0VojI).
Author: unknown!

Comment: Old question but this link works in v8.0.6

Answer (score 1):

JSONAce extension works for Safari 8:

[https://extensions.apple.com/details/?id=com.acrogenesis.jsonace-56Q494QF3L](https://web.archive.org/web/20160416221516/https://extensions.apple.com/details/?id=com.acrogenesis.jsonace-56Q494QF3L)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a JSON prettifier for Safari 8 and I found one which is submitted in the Extensions directory

https://extensions.apple.com/details/?id=com.acrogenesis.jsonview-56Q494QF3L

Hope this helps somebody

Comment: Doesn't work for me.. :(

Comment: You cannot install it or it doesn't show the JSON?

Comment: It doesn't show the formatted json. It appears installed in Safari preferences. I ended up installing the one linked in the accepted answer.