# Program to auto-format JSON responses?

Tags: json, jsonp

Just wondering if theres a program you can paste a JSON response into and it will be auto-formatted? Im finding it very annoying to try and sift through these in the browser to figure out the data structure.

Hopefully this isn't too asinine of me to ask... :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're viewing it in a browser you can use something like this to have it pretty-printed in the browser itself: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc

There's one for Firefox too.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) which will also validate your JSON.

Another alternative I find useful is to output a `<pre>` tag prior to your json, or set the headers of your page to output JSON (e.g. PHP: `header('Content-type: application/json');`).

Answer (score 0):

There is another question that deals with that particularly for the browser: [Browser JSON Plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547769/browser-json-plugins)