# How to serialize a python dict to text, in a human-readable way?

Tags: python, serialization, readability, human-readable

I have an python `dict` whose keys and values are strings, integers and other dicts and tuples ([json does not support those](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7001606/850781)). I want to save it to a text file and then read it from the file.
**Basically, I want a [`read`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rd_rd.htm) counterpart to the built-in [`print`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_wr_pr.htm)** (like in Lisp).

Constraints:

1. the file must be human readable (thus [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) is out)
2. no need to detect circularities.

Is there anything better than [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)?

Comment: What would make something better than json in your estimation?

Comment: @BrenBarn: `read` which matches `print`

Comment: @sds what do you mean read is for input print is for output ... they are two fundamentally different things

Comment: cf [print](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_wr_pr.htm) and [read](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rd_rd.htm)

Comment: Honestly, json is your answer, and that's why it's taken over in the least 5 years. What legibility issues does json have? There are tons of json indenter and pretty-printer utilities - use them and it is human-readable. json is also extremely performant.

Comment: @smci: yes, I am afraid I will have to stick with json

Comment: @sds: honestly, it's briliant. Just find a nice indenter/pretty-printer you like, associate it with .json file type, and you'll never look back. There are tons of blazing fast and performant json libraries. The 'human-readibility' thingy is only a psychological hurdle. I had the same reaction as you when I first saw it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `repr()` on the `dict`, then read it back in and parse it with `ast.literal_eval()`. It's as human readable as Python itself is.

Example:

```
In [1]: import ast

In [2]: x = {}

In [3]: x['string key'] = 'string value'

In [4]: x[(42, 56)] = {'dict': 'value'}

In [5]: x[13] = ('tuple', 'value')

In [6]: repr(x)
Out[6]: "{(42, 56): {'dict': 'value'}, 'string key': 'string value', 13: ('tuple', 'value')}"

In [7]: with open('/tmp/test.py', 'w') as f: f.write(repr(x))

In [8]: with open('/tmp/test.py', 'r') as f: y = ast.literal_eval(f.read())

In [9]: y
Out[9]:
{13: ('tuple', 'value'),
 'string key': 'string value',
 (42, 56): {'dict': 'value'}}

In [10]: x == y
Out[10]: True
```

You may also consider using the `pprint` module for even friendlier formatted output.

Comment: its worth noting that `simplejson` is orders of magnitude faster than this although this is slightly faster than naive `json`

Comment: @JoranBeasley That's good to know. I can't think of much else that's as simple to implement as JSON and similarly human readable.

Comment: Given json's inability to handle tuple keys, this seems to be the _only_ answer. Thanks.

Comment: If the output of `repr()` is insufficiently pretty for you, you may also want to consider the pprint function from the pprint module, which is designed to pretty-print python objects in a more readable way. The output of `pprint()` can just as easily be parsed by `ast.literal_eval()`.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, json is your answer [EDIT: so long as the keys are strings, didn't see the part about dicts as keys], and that's why it's taken over in the least 5 years. What legibility issues does json have? There are tons of json indenter, pretty-printer utilities, browser plug-ins [1][2] - use them and it certainly is human-readable. json(/simplejson) is also extremely performant (C implementations), and it scales, and can be processed serially, which cannot be said for the AST approach (why be eccentric and break scalability?).

This also seems to be the consensus from 100% of people answering you here... everyone can't be wrong ;-) XML is dead, good riddance.

1. [How can I pretty-print JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352098/how-can-i-pretty-print-json) and countless others
2. [Browser JSON Plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547769/browser-json-plugins)

Comment: sorry, ["json is your answer" is BS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001606/json-serialize-a-dictionary-with-tuples-as-key)

Comment: @sds: you need to explain why, you can't just post a swearword. For what it's worth, I experimented with other formats over a couple of years until I reluctantly came to the same conclusion. There are very solid reasons (faster parsing, performance, standardization, tons of third-party tools/ utilities/ libraries).

Comment: @sds Also you need to articulate a better method: the OP's AST approach, or something else?

Comment: The link clearly explains that json cannot serialize quite a lot of objects.

Comment: I don't have a better method; if I did - I would not have asked here. However, json cannot be an answer. It might be that one could write a json-based serializer, but the simple "use `json.dump`" is definitely not an answer the serialization question.

Comment: So: JSON only supports strings as keys, tuples/lists/dicts/sets/arbitrary objects not allowed. Would need to workaround. Depends on what the OP's dict keys are. See [Best way to encode tuples with json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715550/best-way-to-encode-tuples-with-json)

Comment: Nope, it does not depend on my actual data. "Serialization" means universality. It means that any object which can be meaningfully saved and restored should be handled seamlessly (e.g., I am not asking for an ability to save/restore streams).